# How to get page break character in pycharm

Tags: regex, pdftotext

So extracting text with pdftotext is quicker if you have it all in one file instead of one page per file. There is a special character being used as page break, but pycharm does not register it if I search for it. In sublime it shows up as <0x0c>. I cannot copy it here either. Is there a way to replace them with another readable character? Or to read it somehow to register when a page has changed?

Comment: `0x0C` in hex is a form feed. Read the file in binary mode and you should have no issues dealing with it.

Comment: Try using '\f'.

Comment: Thanks reading it in binary mode solved it